# How to allow a radio button to be toggled as you click it?

Tags: android, radio-button

In my android app, I dynamically insert `RadioButton` and I am not using `RadioGroup`. How can I set it so that when you click a radio button its state toggles? So this would be like a check box, but you can only select 1 of them or none.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can write a onclick function which will deselect the another radio button and vice versa. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: I figured out how to de-select other radio buttons, but I dont understand how to toggle it, because on the onclick event, it happens after the radio button changes state so I wouldn't know if it was checked or unchecked before.

Comment: You can check the current state of radio button via isChecked() function and write the logic accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want is exactly what `RadioGroup` does. There's no sense programming this behavior yourself when it already exists for you, so add a `RadioGroup` to your layout (either in XML or in code), then dynamically add the `RadioButton`s to the `RadioGroup`.

Comment: But in my case, I dont want the radio buttons to be together. I am spreading them out and there will be textedit views and image buttons between the radio buttons. As well how does a radiogroup allow you to de-select a radio button is you click it again?

Comment: It doesn't let you deselect one by pressing again, but you might be able to extend RadioGroup and/or RadioButton to implement this. Or you can have a button that clears the checked RadioButton (by calling `RadioGroup.clearCheck()`. As for them being spread out, RadioGroup is just an extension of LinearLayout; you can put Views other than RadioButton inside of it, and it will only enforce the mutual exclusion on RadioButtons inside of it ;)